# 3d arrays in python

Tags: python, matlab

I have used Matlab to develop a set of code. I want to know that how can write this code in python:

```
for header=1:rows
for x=1:length(y)
if(y(x)==initial)
answer(x,1:3,header)=matrix(x,1:3)
end
end
end
```

i have tried to covert loops and if in python syntax but main problem is to write answer(x,1:3,header)=matrix(x,1:3) this statement in which i have to create a 3d array and assign values of matrix to it where matrix is a 2d array containing many rows and 3 columns.

```
code in python:
  for header in range (matrix.nrows): 
  for x in range(matrix.nrows): 
   if y[x] == initial: 
      answer={} 
      answer[x,0:2,header]=matrix[x,0:2]
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing this in plain Python, or are you using Numpy or maybe Pandas?

Comment: You just wanted to create 3d array in python, right?

Comment: i am doing this in plain python.

Comment: Yes right i want to know how i'll create the same thing in python

Comment: You should show us the Python code you've tried, even though it's wrong. BTW, if your array is large it would be a good idea to use Numpy. Handling large multidimensional arrays in plain Python is slow. but in Numpy it can be almost as fast as compiled code.

Comment: Plain python looks nothing like matlab - numpy does. Install numpy and see its documentation.

Comment: for row in range(matrix.nrows):

    y = matrix.cell_value(row, 0)


for header in range (matrix.nrows):

    for x in range(matrix.nrows):

        if y[x] == initial:

            answer={}

            answer[x,0:2,header]=sheet[x,0:2]

Comment: Yes array is large. thanks for suggestion. I'll try using numpy. But still can i do it using plain python?

Comment: in last statement i hv made a mistake it is matrix instead of sheet: answer[x,0:2,header]=matrix[x,0:2]

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the requested code so that you can show proper formatting.

Comment: What data type is `matrix`? Because I can't find any built-in python type that has that attribute. Is it your own class or are you using an external package?

Comment: matrix is just the name of my 2D array